# Linux distribution with built-in ffmpeg library

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, linux-distro

Is there a Linux distribution with a built-in *ffmpeg* library (compiled) ?

It seems to cause a lot of problems to install *ffmpeg* these days (for development). No matter how hard I tried using this [wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide), it refuses to link properly. A lot of undefined references...

Answer (score 1):

Just run `sudo pacman -S ffmpeg` on Arch based distros.

I recommend Manjaro. It's an amazing distro with great convenience because it has access to the AUR or Arch User Repository. AUR is basically the biggest repository in any Linux distro. It's like an app store that has pretty much everything that's available on Linux. That's an over-simplification but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try UbuntuStudio? Judging by http://ubuntustudio.org/tour/video/, it has ffmpeg pre-installed.

Comment: does it come with ffmpeg libraries for development?

Answer (score 0):

You always can try source based distros like **Gentoo**, **Slackware** and **Arch**. In my experience, Gentoo have a good build result ( the ebuild runs fine, just `emerge ffmpeg` ). And you have the advantage to make it to your needs. Take care about `./configure` options. Sometimes a feature can f*** the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

openSUSE offers ffmpeg in [Packman repository](http://en.opensuse.org/Additional_package_repositories#Packman)